# How to remove `duplicates' in list of instances

Tags: python, class, duplicates, instance

I have a list of instances of a certain class. This list contains `duplicates', in the sense that duplicates share the exact same attributes. I want to remove the duplicates from this list.

I can check whether two instances share the same attributes by using

```
class MyClass:

    def __eq__(self, other) : 
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

I could of course iterate through the whole list of instances and compare them element by element to remove duplicates, but I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do this, preferably using the in operator + list comprehension.

Comment: You could make them hashable and then use `set` to eliminate duplicates

Comment: NB the set approach will not preserve any ordering in your list.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: The version is Python 3. @vaultah I guess it should be possible to construct a hash from .__dict__ method that satisfies my requirements?

Answer (score 4):

## `set`s (no order)

A set cannot contain duplicate elements. `list(set(content))` will deduplicate a list. This is not too inefficient and is probably one of the better ways to do it :P You will need to define a `__hash__` function for your class though, which must be the same for equal elements and different for unequal elements for this to work. Note that the `hash` value must obey the aforementioned rule but otherwise it may change between runs without causing issues.

## `index` function (stable order)

You could do `lambda l: [l[index] for index in range(len(l)) if index == l.index(l[index])]`. This only keeps elements that are the first in the list.

## `in` operator (stable order)

```
def uniquify(content):
    result = []
    for element in content:
        if element not in result:
            result.append(element)
    return result
```

This will keep appending elements to the output list unless they are already in the output list.

Answer (score 2):

A little more on the set approach. You can safely implement a hash by delegating to a tuple's hash - just hash a tuple of all the attributes you want to look at. You will also need to define an `__eq__` that behaves properly.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c) == (other.a, other.b, other.c)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyClass({!r}, {!r}, {!r})".format(self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

As you're doing so much tuple construction, you could just make your class iterable:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter((self.a, self.b, self.c))
```

This enables you to call `tuple` on `self` instead of laboriously doing `.a, .b, .c` etc.

You can then do something like this:

```
def unordered_elim(l):
    return list(set(l))
```

If you want to preserve ordering, you can use an `OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def ordered_elim(l):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l).keys())
```

This should be faster than using `in` or `index`, while still preserving ordering. You can test it something like this:

```
data = [MyClass("this", "is a", "duplicate"),
        MyClass("first", "unique", "datum"),
        MyClass("this", "is a", "duplicate"),
        MyClass("second", "unique", "datum")]

print(unordered_elim(data))
print(ordered_elim(data))
```

With this output:

```
[MyClass('first', 'unique', 'datum'), MyClass('second', 'unique', 'datum'), MyClass('this', 'is a', 'duplicate')]
[MyClass('this', 'is a', 'duplicate'), MyClass('first', 'unique', 'datum'), MyClass('second', 'unique', 'datum')]
```

NB if any of your attributes aren't hashable, this won't work, and you'll either need to work around it (change a list to a tuple) or use a slow, `n ^ 2` approach like `in`.

Comment: @ZachGates  I'm not sure I understand - as far as I'm concerned, `MyClass(1, 2, 3) != MyClass(3, 2, 1)` (this is also implied by OP - they will have a different `dict`.). As for `hash(self) == hash(other)` - the whole reason we need `__eq__` is to disambiguate when there's a hash collision.