# remove (graph) isomorphic instances from python list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, networkx, isomorphism

Given a function that returns `True` if two instances `A` and `B` of some class are the "same", is there an efficient way of to remove duplicates from a list?

My question is general, but the example I have in mind are `networkx` graphs and the function is `networkx.is_isomorphic`. Two graphs that have the same shape are said isomorphic, but the attributes of the two `networkx.Graph` instances can be different. From a list `li`, I want to get only graphs that have different shapes.

A solution I came up with is the following:

```
def check_isomorphisms(G, new_li):
    for H in new_li:
        if are_isomorphic(G, H):
            return True
    return False

def remove_isomorphisms(li):
    if li == []:
        return li
    new_li = [li[0]]
    for G in li:
        if check_isomorphisms(G, new_li) is True:
            continue
        else:
            new_li.append(G)

    return new_li
```

In the practical example above `are_isomorphic = networkx.is_isomorphic`, but it is a priori independent of the particular class of objects and the precise definition of isomorphic, as long as there is a function that returns either true or false given two instances.

It is a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567232/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-instances), but in that case two instances are the same if there attributes are the same so hashing was easy, and there was not really a need for optimisation. I'm interested in cases where "the same" is more general.

The solution I came up with works, but scales terribly with the size of the list. For about a list with 1000 elements, it takes about a minute, while it takes half an hour with 4000 elements (working with graphs and graph isomorphisms), while on the other hand building the the original list with duplicates takes a few seconds. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: No, you cannot do better than that if *all* you have is that `isSame` function. You can do better if you have some other metric to group items by, such that if items are the same, it follows they are in the same group. In the example of graphs, the number of nodes in the graph can be such a metric. We can think of many more. The smaller the groups are, the better the performance, as you only need to call the `isSame` function on pairs that belong to the same group.